# Which comes first? The char or the String?

Tags: java, if-statement, char, stringbuilder, uppercase

Most of the examples I find in my search for the answer are embedded in complex code.  I'm just trying to have a question program know to accept either upper or lower case responses to a two-answer (binary?) question and then to use either answer to proceed to a singular result.  I tried an if/else approach before I found character class methods in my book, but it only helps half way with it's examples.

here's the code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class MarriageQuiz
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
  char isMarried = 'M';
  char isSingle = 'S';
  String marStat;

  System.out.print("Please enter your Marital Status (M or S) >> ");
  marStat = input.nextLine();

     if(marStat.isUppercase(isMarried | isSingle))
     {
        marStat = input.nextLine();
     }
     else if((marStat.isLowercase(isMarried | isSingle)))
     {
        marStat = marStat.toUpperCase(isMarried | isSingle);
     }
     System.out.print("You are " + marStat);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm flirting with the idea of using a boolean with this

Comment: I thought about using StingBuilder but I still have to identify the string to be edited.

Comment: What exactly is your Question? Another thing, the logic of your code example does not make sense, the purpose cannot be discerned.

Comment: If I ask "Please enter your Marital Status"  how can I have the program understand that 'M' is the same as 'm' and 'S' is the same as 's'?  Then use it for the input for marStat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert all input to your expected case (upper or lowercase, you pick one).

No harm done in trying to convert a character to one case that happens to already be in that case. The `toUppercase` method does not complain when you call it needlessly. So no need to test for case at all.

```
marStat = marStat.toUppercase() ;
if ( marStat.equals( 'S' ) {
    … do Single stuff
} else if ( marStat.equals( 'M' ) {
    … do Married stuff
} else {
    … handle unexpected input
}
```

---

Tip: if running this code a zillion times, consider replacing the use of the `char` primitive with the `Character` class to avoid the autoboxing discussed in [the Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: Any new coders out there would do well to remember this "pattern" -- you'll use it over and over in your career whenever you're comparing user input to some known string.

Comment: @RyanMartin ??? Make the M & S into what?

Comment: Never-mind.  I think you answered my question though.  I want to use 'M' or 'S' in my if/else actions I just didn't know how to get it to be recognized regardless of case.

Comment: I don't think I even needed the char of either

Answer (score 0):

`isUppercase` and `isLowercase` doesn't work like that at all. And your code makes little sense.

It seems like that you want to compare characters only, but you called `nextLine` which returns a `String`. And in the if statements, somehow you are asking for user input *again*. I don't really know what you're doing here.

I guess you want something like this:

```
char isMarried = 'M';
char isSingle = 'S';
char marStat;

System.out.print("Please enter your Marital Status (M or S) >> ");
marStat = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

if(marStat == 's' || marStat == 'S')
{
   System.out.println("You are single!");
}
else if(marStat == 'm' || marStat == 'M')
{
   System.out.println("You are married!");
}
```

I don't think you fully understand how programming works.